# WPF - can't access template elements for objects created at runtime

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create a checkable variation of the `ComboBox` control using a custom `ControlTemplate`.  The eventual aim is to add a click handler for the integrated `CheckBox` every time a new `ComboBoxItem` is created - but when I use `(CheckBox)template.FindName("myCheckBox", item);` it always returns null.

Here is the Style that sets the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="CheckedComboBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="8"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="myStackPanel" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox" Focusable="False" Width="50" Foreground="{StaticResource textBrush}"
                                          IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, 
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    <ContentPresenter></ContentPresenter>
                                </CheckBox>
                                <TextBlock x:Name="myTextBlock" Text="{Binding Name}"  Width="100" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and here is the code that tries to get a reference to the CheckBox in the code behind whenever a new item is added to the `ComboBox`:

```
            ComboBoxItem item = new ComboBoxItem();
            item.Content = system.Name;
            item.Tag = system.Id;
            cbSystems.Items.Add(item);
            item.Loaded += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var template = item.Template;
                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)template.FindName("myCheckBox", item);
                MessageBox.Show(chkBox.Name);
            };
```

Comment: You're using Binding why do you need to have an event handler? Using Tag? This is 2020 not 1997. DataContext of the comboboxitem will hold all the information for you. Are you trying to do WInForms in WPF? If so your're into a world of pain. read up on MvvM and how to apply `DataTemplates`. Trust me it will save you loads of time.

Comment: @XAMlMAX Because I don't know how to make a ComboBox with extra check boxes without handling the check events separately.  The tag property is needed for another reason that is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: Like I said, if you were to read on mvvm and how to structure the model then you would have selected property, to which you `BIND` checkbox's IsChecked. No need for pre historic event handlers! And for the love of programming, make sure your model implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` is there any design/thought gone into the app you're working on or is it typical WinForms "Let's put everything everywhere and make it static"? And those control names are absolutely irrelevant.